# Selenium WebDriver Python Наведение курсора мыши на объект

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, тестирование

Теперь наведение происходит, но появляющаяся кнопка упорно не нажимается

```py
hover = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[text()='МТС Деньги Weekend']")  # Наведение мыши
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(hover).perform()
hover.perform()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"result\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]").click()
```

Comment: Я уверен, что вам поможет это решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252558/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-mouseover-hover-over-an-element-using-selenium-and

Comment: Почему вы решили, что наведения не было? Может вы просто не замечаете, так как тест заканчивается?

Comment: @German  Спасибо за ответ. Помогло

Comment: Да. Теперь наведение есть, но он упорно не нажимает на появляющуюся кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

Все. Сам разобрался.
Надо убрать `hover = и hover.perform()`.
Все заработало